# highlight CSS code in textarea like an IDE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textarea where an user can add CSS code and the code is applied to the site

[image]

but the textarea is not styled, it shows all the code as normal text.

most of the libraries I have found are too big for the only thing I need,

I need a simple textarea that can highlight the css code like codepen or jsfiddle but only for css code

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries such as [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) that allows you to do this

Comment: textarea is unneditable with that library

Comment: you can put this inside a <pre><code> tag and use the contentEditable attribute no ?

Comment: oh! thanks! but now I can't get the content, exists a function for that?

Comment: element.innerText ?